# inflow/outflow Boundary Conditions for flow in pipe

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis

I have a question about boundary condition of solving Navier-Stokes equation through pipe.
When I simulate the flow in pipe using periodic boundary condition, it works good. But when I tried to change boundary condition into inflow/outflow condition, then after few iteration, it started to blow up. 
I'm using a levelset method for interface capturing and general projection method for solving Navier-Stokes equations.
I just imposed inflow/outflow boundary condition for velocity and levelset as simple linear extrapolation of inside one.
Is there anyway to treat inflow/outflow boundary condition? $\triangle$

Comment: for a meaningful response form this site, you'll want to formulate your issue as a mathematical problem, rather than "if I do this my program crashes"

Comment: Thank for comment Carlo. I'll fix this with mathematical formulation.